# Canvas positioning in kivy using self.size

Tags: python, kivy

I have a little problem with canvas positioning in kivy. I want to use size of the screen so one Rectangle ends up in upper right corner of the screen and other is at (0, 0) but the y of the screen when rectangles are drawn is 100 for some reason even though it obviously is not. Here is the code, it would be easier that way for you to understand. Please tell me what am I missing? And of course if you have some questions please ask.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle


class GameWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:

            print(self.size[1])
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos=(0, 0), size=(150, 150))
            self.rect2 = Rectangle(pos=self.size, size=(150, 150))


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return GameWidget()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.run()
```

Comment: You draw your Rectangles based on self.size at the moment of instantiation, which at this point is (100, 100). You need to bind a function to the GameWidget resize event, and in the callback update your Rectangle positions.

Comment: you have to listen for resize... or just use a proportional sizing widget...

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you post some code? I understood it partially but not fully. Thanks again.

Comment: @inclement is there a way to draw these Rectangles when the window is fully loaded? Or could you clarify the solution with resize event?

Comment: http://inclem.net/2019/12/18/kivy/kivy_tutorial_005_a_drawing_app/